# Discrete Math: If tomorrow is not Tuesday, then yesterday was not Sunday

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone confirm the answer below?

If tomorrow is not Tuesday, then yesterday was not Sunday.

Yesterday was Sunday.

Therefore, **tomorrow is Tuesday?**

This is Modus Tollens, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct and simply an application of *modus tollens.*

Comment: Thank you. I got confused for a moment.